# i want to install java on Ubuntu 13.04, but i got this type of problem during installing java

Tags: 13.04, apt, java, dpkg, software-installation

problem is that:

```
apt-get install default-jre
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

before that i 've already run update command it was ok but at last i got this type of message:

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

Comment: In Ubuntu (not ubantu) people use `sudo` in front of `apt-get` command to get the right privileges to install something.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure software center is not running

1. `ps -e|grep software-center`

then use sudo  with you apt-get command

1. `sudo apt-get update`
2. `sudo apt-get install default-jre`